# How do I toggle alerts when a core file is modified?

Tags: notification, core

A month ago my site got hacked. I only found out there was a problem because I got an email alert saying 'a core file on your site has been modified'. Now we've been hacked twice in the same week by the same people, and I haven't had that email alert telling me to fix it. How do I re-enable this?

And yes, I am focusing on trying to stop them from hacking at the moment.

Comment: Oh that really stinks. Hackers suck. Is it possible they got in deep enough to turn off your outbound SMTP services? Have you confirmed EE on your server can send out other types of email?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've found a simple solution - uninstall EE. We installed it thinking we'd need to create a webapp, but we ended up going for a php solution. We don't need it.